# dateutil.parser.parse does not return a correct datetime

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series

I tried the following line of code, which returns a strange result.

```
In [68]:
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
​
parse('2017/JAN')

Out[68]:
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 6, 0, 0)
```

Since the parser was ordered to parse a date-time string up to January, one may reasonably assume that the output should be the first day of the month, namely, 2017/January/1.

However, strangely, the ouput was 2017/January/6, of which date is coincidentally same to the date on my Windows PC.

So I tried changing the date to yesterday (Feb/5) and the output changed to datetime(2017, 1, 5, 0, 0), which is 2017/JAN/5.

It appears that the parser picks up a date from the calendar of a local compter that it is running on, in case date is not specified as a function argument.

Is this behavior by design or maybe a bug? If it is intended, what would be a rationale?

Thank you

Comment: can u give a clarification of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) package.

Thers must be different formats for parsing:

If u need more details just see this [parse link](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html)

EDIT:A small example for u,

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float("1294989360"))
```

Comment: thank you for answering. The document web page for dateutil does not mention what happens if date is unspecified in the date time string passed to the parser but just year and month. I was trying to use parser as a handy way to create datetime.

Comment: then i will give u a simple example